# How to prevent access to a subLocation

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, apache2.4

I have a webapp hidden behind Apache 2.4 which is set as a proxy

My configuration goes like this:

```
<Location /myapp>
Proxypass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp
Require all granted
</Location>
```

Recently, I was asked to prevent anyone but whitelisted IPs to access to myapp API which is accessible through /myapp/api/

I am failing to achieve proper configuration within Apache to make it so

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
<Location /myapp/api>
Proxypass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/api
Require local
Require 1.2.3.4
</Location>


<Location /myapp>
Proxypass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp
Require all granted
</Location>
```

So what I need is for http://mysite/myapp/ to be accessible to anyone, but to restrict calls to http://mysite/myapp/api/* to a bunch of whitelised IP

Do you know how I may be able to achieve this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [Overlapping Webspace](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#file-and-web), you should reverse the order of *Location* directives

```
 <Location /myapp>
Proxypass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp
Require all granted
</Location>

<Location /myapp/api>
Proxypass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/api
Require local
Require 1.2.3.4
</Location>
```